# Not able to login to magento admin after domain name mapping

Tags: magento2

0

I have just migrate magento code from 2.2.5 to 2.4.3-p1 to a different server and enviroment. Parent domain and Sub-domain are hosted on cloudflare. As xyz.com and test.xyz.com.

I am not able to login to frontenad backend admin portal. Even after using correct credentials.

Action already taken: update core_config_data table in db as changed cookie domain value to .test.xyz.com , test.xyz.com , NULL , blank. Nothing is working . Pls help.

Delete cookies and cache from browser and magento. For Session storage i am using AWS Elast-cache Redis.

Comment: bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Might want to create a new user with new password.  Magento sometimes resets the password and you can't unlock the user and have to create a new one....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to reboot your server and flush cache.
it might be 'Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page' error but didn't show message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).